# How to remove hash keys which hash value is blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, key-value

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.13 and I would like to remove hash keys which corresponding hash value is blank. That is, if I have the following hash

```
{ :a => 0, :b => 1, :c => true, :d => "", :e => "   ", :f => nil }
```

then the resulting hash should be (note: `0` and `true` are not considered blank)

```
{ :a => 0, :b => 1, :c => true }
```

How can I make that?

Comment: Do you want to keep `:g => []` and `h => {}`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If using Rails you can try

```
hash.delete_if { |key, value| value.blank? }
```

or in case of just Ruby

```
hash.delete_if { |key, value| value.to_s.strip == '' }
```

Comment: `value.to_s.strip.empty?` reads a bit better than `== ''`, IMO. Also, you don’t need Rails to have `blank?`, just ActiveSupport.

Comment: what if the value is a hash that is empty? or further nested hash is empty?

Answer (score 19):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this common task

## reject

This is the one I use most often for cleaning up hashes as its short, clean, and flexible enough to support any conditional and **doesn't mutate the original object**. Here is a [good article](http://www.rubypigeon.com/posts/avoid-mutation-functional-style-in-ruby/) on the benefits of immutability in ruby.

```
hash.reject {|_,v| v.blank?}
```

Note: The underscore in the above example is used to indicate that we want to unpack the tuple passed to the proc, but we aren't using the first value (key).

## reject!

However, if you want to mutate the original object:

```
hash.reject! {|_,v| v.blank?}
```

## select

Conversely, you use select which will only return the values that return true when evaluated

```
hash.select {|_,v| v.present? }
```

## select!

...and the mutating version

```
hash.select {|_,v| v.present? }
```

## compact

Lastly, when you ***only*** need to remove keys that have `nil` values...

```
hash.compact
```

## compact!

You have picked up the pattern by now, but this is the version that modifies the original hash!

```
hash.compact!
```

Answer (score 0):

With respect to techvineet's solution, note the following when value == [].

```
[].blank?               => true 
[].to_s.strip == ''     => false 
[].to_s.strip.empty?    => false
```